# FTP BAT Script Doesn't work. Goes in a LOOP by itself

Tags: batch-file, ftp, echo

I have an FTP Script with the following command

```
FTP -v -i -s: ftpscr.txt
```

The text file ftpscr.txt contains the following:

```
open 10.195.8.165
ftp-user
ftpuser
cd reports/APSummary

@echo off
setlocal
for /f "tokens=2-7 delims=_.-" %%A in ('dir /B TACO_*') do (
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  call :getmonth %%B
  ren TACO*_*%%A-%%B-%%C*_*%%D-%%E-%%F_UTC.csv TACO_%%A!mon!%%C_%%D%%E%%F.csv
  endlocal
)


:getmonth
if "%1" equ "Jan" set mon=01
if "%1" equ "Feb" set mon=02
if "%1" equ "Mar" set mon=03
if "%1" equ "Apr" set mon=04
if "%1" equ "May" set mon=05
if "%1" equ "Jun" set mon=06
if "%1" equ "Jul" set mon=07
if "%1" equ "Aug" set mon=08
if "%1" equ "Sep" set mon=09
if "%1" equ "Oct" set mon=10
if "%1" equ "Nov" set mon=11
if "%1" equ "Dec" set mon=12
goto :eof
endlocal
```

When i execute the file ftp.bat which contains the ftp script the command prompt keeps on repeating with no results... Please help

Comment: its not looping now but the command i have given doesnt seem to run... any idea why??
The command starting from echo is a rename function which is changeing the date fromat in the file on the ftp server

Comment: thanks got it running.....just one more thing the command below starting from echo is to be in a bat file how do run the program after it has changed the directory

Comment: Well here is the thing.  I need to go into the ftp server and then run the script to change the file name.  How can i get it to work.  Advanced Thanks for your help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23064/discussion-between-user1991965-and-rene)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have  to rename the ftp.bat to myftp.bat

and your ftp command has an errournous space after the -s argument

```
FTP -v -i -s:ftpscr.txt
```